# Leaflet grouping layer doesn't show on the map

Tags: django, leaflet, geodjango

I am working in GeoDjango. I am trying to add leaflet group from [here](https://github.com/ismyrnow/leaflet-groupedlayercontrol). I copied files from the dist folder to my folder with the static files and imported them into HTML file. Anyway I have some problem with this part of code:

```
//GROUP LAYER
        var osm = 
'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}{y}{x}.png';
        var baseLayers = {
            "OSM":osm
        }

        var groupedOverlays = {
            "layers": {
            "layer1": datasets_buildings,
            "layer2": datasets_roads,
            "layer3": datasets_railways,
            "layer4": datasets_natural

            }
        };
        L.control.groupedLayers(baseLayers, groupedOverlays, options).addTo(map);
```

When I typed this, I don't even get my layers on the map, I get just the empty leaflet map and without this part of the code, I get it. 
Also, I would like to make functionality to this layer group which allows only one layer to be active.

This is all my code:

```
<html lang="en">

{% load static %}
{% load leaflet_tags %}

<head>
    {% leaflet_js %}
    {% leaflet_css %}
    <style type="text/css">
      #gis {
        width: 100%;
        height: 870px;
    }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type = 'text/css' href="{%  static 'maps/dist/leaflet.groupedlayercontrol.css' %}">
<script type="text/javascript" src="{%  static 'maps/dist/leaflet.ajax.js'%}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{%  static 'maps/dist/leaflet.groupedlayercontrol.js' %}"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

  function our_layers(map,options){
        //buildings
        var datasets_buildings = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX(" 
  {% url 'buildings_json_data' %}",{
            onEachFeature : function (feature, layer) {
                layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name.toString())
            }
        });

        //roads
        var datasets_roads = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("{% url 'roads_json_data' %}",{
            onEachFeature : function (feature, layer) {
                layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name.toString())
            }
        });

        //railways
        var datasets_railways = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("{% url 'railways_json_data' %}",{
            onEachFeature : function (feature, layer) {
                layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name.toString())
            }
        });

        //natural
        var datasets_natural = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("{% url 'natural_json_data' %}",{
            onEachFeature : function (feature, layer) {
                layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name.toString())
            }
        });
        datasets_natural.addTo(map);
        datasets_railways.addTo(map);
        datasets_roads.addTo(map);
        datasets_buildings.addTo(map);




        //GROUP LAYER
        var osm = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}{y}{x}.png';
        var baseLayers = {
            "OSM":osm
        }

        var groupedOverlays = {
            "layers": {
            "layer1": datasets_buildings,
            "layer2": datasets_roads,
            "layer3": datasets_railways,
            "layer4enter code here": datasets_natural

            }
        };
        L.control.groupedLayers(baseLayers, groupedOverlays, options).addTo(map);
    }


</script>

    {%  leaflet_map "gis" callback="window.our_layers" %}


</body>






</html>
```

And the error when I get in the console when I go on inspect is:

```
 leaflet.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property '_leaflet_id' on string 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}{y}{x}.png'
at Object.n [as stamp] (leaflet.js:5)
at e._addLayer (leaflet.groupedlayercontrol.js:131)
at e.initialize (leaflet.groupedlayercontrol.js:26)
at new e (leaflet.js:5)
at Function.L.control.groupedLayers (leaflet.groupedlayercontrol.js:373)
at Object.our_layers [as callback] ((index):96)
at Function.L.Map.djangoMap (leaflet.extras.js:234)
at loadmap ((index):112)
```

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a mistake. I knew it was stupid, but I lost so much time on this and I posted a question..

Anyway, the line:

```
var osm = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}{y}{x}.png';
```

should be replace with this line:

```
var osm = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}{y}{x}.png');
```